# Creating a lot of actions in Zend Framework

Tags: performance, zend-framework

I work with the Zend Framework.

I have 3 requests from a controller.

I can create an action for 3 of those requests or create 3 actions for 3 of those requests (3 requests same function).

If I create an action, I must check some conditions. It's hard for me to develop,
but if I create 3 actions, does that matter?

I learned about classes in OOP.
When computers run code in a class, properties are saved in memory, and the method is saved in a virtual table on the computer. I think if I have less actions, it can give better performance.

Should I create 3 actions or 1 action?

Answer (score 3):

In a web application, the overhead from code size should be negligible. Just organize your controllers so they're readable and maintainable.